# Как вызвать нестатический метод в статическом в Java?

Tags: java, ооп

Здравствуйте! Создал нестатический метод `logger`. Он считывает стэк ошибки , вызываемый при каком-либо `Exception`'е , и выводит в графический интерфейс. Так как этот метод нестатический , вызвать его из статического метода нельзя. Объявить его статичным нельзя, так как я использую методы `setContentPane` и `setSize` , которые также не статичны. Что посоветуете сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В статическом методе создать класс и вызвать из созданного класса нестатический метод. Примерно так:

```
class ClassName{

public ClassName(){
}

public static sMethod(){
new ClassName().nsMethod();
}

public nsMethod(){
println('Не статический метод')
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если создать экземпляр класса, можно пользоваться его нестатическими методами из статического метода:

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] numbers = {1,3,5,7,6,4,2}; 

            // создаем экземпляр, чтоб вызывать нестатический метод
            Main main = new Main(); 
            System.out.println(main.minFromArray(numbers));
        }

        // наш нестатический метод:
        public Integer minFromArray(int[] numbers) {
        var min = Arrays.stream(numbers).min().getAsInt(); 
        return min;
        }
   }
```